# Using URLS that accept slashes as part of the parameter in Django

Tags: python, django

Is there a way in Django to accept 'n' parameters which are delimited by a '/' (forward slash)?

I was thinking this may work, but it does not. Django still recognizes forward slashes as delimiters.

```
(r'^(?P<path>[-\w]+/)$', 'some.view', {}),
```

Comment: What do you mean by accept parameters?

Comment: The reason that doesn't work is becuase [-\w]+ includes a hyphen and \w (which is alphanumeric + underscore). You need to expand your criteria to include a /, either by adding / to the character class or by (as per Ian's answer) using something more liberal to begin with, like .*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the right url to your urlpatterns:

```
# ...
("^foo/(.*)$", "foo"), # or whatever
# ...
```

And process it in your view, like AlbertoPL said:

```
fields = paramPassedInAccordingToThatUrl.split('/')
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, Django can accept any URL which can be described by a regular expression - including one which has a prefix followed by a '/' followed by a variable number of segments separated by '/'. The exact regular expression will depend on what you want to accept - but an example in Django is given by /admin URLs which parse the suffix of the URL in the view.